# Install Kubernetes on Red Hat Linux (RHEL 7)

Tags: kubernetes, rhel

I am trying to install Kubernetes on Red Hat Linux (RHEL 7) . Any advice on the best and easiest way to do this ? I would not like to use minikube. Thank you very much

Comment: Use `kubeadm` this is easy way of configuring Kubernetes cluster. you can follow the document on the website.

Answer (score 1):

`kubeadm` is the way to go for installing kubernetes on RHEL. Though in alpha, it works for most of the use cases.

You can find the installation instructions on the [kubeadm installation page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/) and steps to use it on the [using kubeadm page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

Answer (score 0):

Best and easy is in the eye of the beholder, but maybe you want to review the install options I tried to describe and categorize in the post [Kubernetes: A Little Guide to Install Options](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-little-guide-install-options/) against your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

this link [https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-1-7-centos7-rhel7/ ] will help you.
1).there is some dependency of Kubernetes make sure that you use docker-engine 1.13.0 (tested).
2).write swapoff -a in your .bashrc file to off swap memory.
3).setup the firewall rules accordingly.
 Happy Learning :)..

Answer (score 0):

[KubeSpray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray) !

Gives you the ability to install addons as well on baremetal and in the cloud and is highly customizable because its all Ansible based.

Initially you just populate the inventory file and choose the options that you want in the variable files and thats it.

The ansible playbook does all the rest for you. And if you want to scale up, there is a playbook for that too.